# Using vlookup over multiple tables to find a product number from the product table based on the product selected from a dropdown list

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have two dynamic tables: Product and Analysis.

On the Analysis table, I have a drop down list in cell H1. It is generated from the Product table.

I want cell H2 to automatically give me the productNo by finding the selected product in the Products table.

How would I do this?

Comment: What have you tried (provide your code)? Did you get an error? If so, what was the error and on what line?  Also, can you provide some sample data and expected results?

Comment: use a VLOOKUP function. Why do yuo need VBA?

Comment: search this site or google for "Vlookup examples"; give it a try and let us know if you have issues

Comment: this is on one table:                                  ProductNo Product
I101 Computer Support
H101 MATTRESS 1
H102 MATTRESS 2
H103 MATTRESS 3
H104 MATTRESS 4
S101 Single Sheet
S102 Double Sheet
S103 Pillow Cases and on another table i have           ProductNo Product
lookup by product name MATTRESS 1 i need to get the productNo automatically once i have selected the product.  there are many tables that i have to do the same thing for

Answer (score 0):

With an arrangement as shown, `=VLOOKUP(H1,J2:K9,2,FALSE)` in H2 should suit:

[image: SO18340613 example]